# SQL Server / hexadecimal string as primary key, which collation to use?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, md5, collation, case-sensitive

I am working on a database where MD5 hashes are used as primary keys on some tables, with the type char(32).

In the past, I only worked with databases using int for primary key but on this project, I have no choice.
I wonder, what collation(s) should be used to deal with a char(32) primary key (which contains an hexadecimal string) ?

**EDIT :**

Currently, the collation of the database is French_CI_AS. I would like to know if it's OK for such kind of primary key or if I should switch to a CS or BIN2 collation to have better performance ?

Comment: WOW. I don't envy you on that. Using an MD5 hash as a primary key is a horrible design. I assume you then have to expand to other tables as the foreign key. What a nightmare. Not sure what the concern about your collation is.

Comment: @Abomb looks like you doesn't had your first informed badge. feel free to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You could store it as a binary(16) instead of a 32 byte string.

Comment: @SeanLange My concern about collation is about case-sensitivity (I should have been more accurate). Should the collation used be a case-sensitive collation (CS in SQL Server world) ?

Comment: I haven't used MD5 in quite awhile but isn't is all lower case? Assuming that is correct the collation shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: @SeanLange indeed, all the MD5 hashes are lower case in the db.

Comment: Do you want to support people searching for both AAAA and aaaa or not? If you want to insist on case sensitivity you might as well use a binary collation for marginal performance reasons.

Comment: @MartinSmith "Do you want to support people searching for both AAAA and aaaa or not?" No sir, the search will always be "aaaa". But if the performance gain is marginal, then I will stay with the current collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't changed the collation during setup, according to this [Microsoft Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260(v=sql.105).aspx) *"When SQL Server Setup detects that the computer is running the U.S. English system locale, Setup automatically selects the Dictionary order, case-insensitive, for use with 1252 character set SQL Server 2008 collation ..."*

There are many Sort order for a collation:

- **Binary (BIN):** Sorts and compares data in SQL Server tables based on the bit patterns defined for each character. Binary sort order is case-sensitive and accent-sensitive. Binary is also the fastest sorting order
- **Binary-Point (BIN2):** Sorts and compares data in SQL Server tables based on Unicode code points for Unicode data. For non-Unicode data, Binary-code point will use comparisons identical to binary sorts
- **Case Sensitive (CS):** Distinguishes between uppercase and lowercase letters. If selected, lowercase letters sort ahead of their uppercase versions.
- **Accent Sensitive (AS):** Distinguishes between accented and unaccented characters. For example, 'a' is not equal to 'ấ'.
- **Kana-sensitive (KS):** Distinguishes between the two types of Japanese kana characters: Hiragana and Katakana.
- **Width-Sensitive (WS):** Distinguishes between a single-byte character and the same character when represented as a double-byte character.

And Hexadecimal values are not case sensitive nor width,kana sensitive. And as you provided in comments the default collation is `French_CI_AS` (which means French - case insensitive - Accent sensitive) so it is case insensitive (which is good) and it is accent sensitive (hexadecimal doesn't contains accented characters so this feature is not necessary, but if chosen it will not affect anything).

So the `French_CI_AS` collation is good for your case

**References**

- [Windows Collation Sorting Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143515(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Selecting a SQL Server Collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx)

---

*Side Note: selecting a HASH code as primary key is not recommended at all!! It is better to choose an integer as primary key*

Comment: Currently, the collation of the database is French_CI_AS. I would like to know if it's OK for such kind of primary key or if I should switch to a CS or BIN2 collation to have better performance ?

Comment: @Abomb hexadecimal is case insensitive, when talking about Binary it is case sensitive. I don't think you should switch collation. If you switched to a case sensitive collation or binary (also case sensitive) it may caused duplicates in primary key values (same value with different cases letters)